# Hi, is there any existing plug in which allows a model to follow a particular path? Or anything close to constraining or planning path of a model

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Suppose I have to move my robot from A to B then C, and under certain constraints on velocity acceleration like dynamic properties? Does there exist any plug in which does the same or anything close to this??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12691/hi,-is-there-any-existing-plug-in-which-allows-a-model-to-follow-a-particular-path?-or-anything-close-to-constraining-or-planning-path-of-a-model-(example:-quad-rotor-or-cart)/) by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2016-02-23**:
You might want to take a look at motion planning in ROS (http://moveit.ros.org)

**Comment by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on 2016-02-26**:
You can also look to the move_base package : http://wiki.ros.org/move_base
Then you add a gazebo_ros plugin like the diff_drive plugin to your model.

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2016-02-26**:
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You might want to take a look at motion planning in ROS (http://moveit.ros.org)

You can also look to the move_base package : http://wiki.ros.org/move_base Then you add a gazebo_ros plugin like the diff_drive plugin to your model.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2016-03-03**:
Thanks!! It did help